# Instagram IGTV cannot be downloaded

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I want to build an android app to download instagram images and videos and igtvs.So I can download pictures easily without need to access token,but for downloading videos I have to have access token to use instagram api and finally I have no idea about downloading igtv.
I uploaded an igtv video on my page(my app is in sandbox mode,but I'm admin) and instagram responds that **"media url is not valid"**.

Comment: you expect to download videos on a private profile? you cant even get pictutres of users without their approval.

Comment: No, I didn't want to do that.
Only I want to download from public pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh It's very easy after one week struggle with Instagram API and searching for find a way!
Get html content of the page and with regex find the download link:
`<meta property="og:video" content="video_link" />`
And this regex will be so useful:

```
        String getVideoUrl(String content) {

        String videoUrl = null;
        String regex = "<meta property=\"og:video\" content=\"(.*?)\" />";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(content);

        if (m.find()) {
            videoUrl = m.group(1);
        }
        return videoUrl;
    }
```

This code will be useful for downloading video and IGTV too.
In addition,to download images this one worked for me:

```
regex = "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"(.*?)\"";
```